# Can Arduino UNO be used to emulate a PS4 joystick?

Tags: usb, joystick

**I Want to know if there is a library that can be used in order to make a PS4 controller with Arduino.**
I have a PS2 steering wheel and I want to use it thorugh Arduino with PS4. I know that PS4 has his own protocol but I think there may be a way to do it.

Cheers!

**EDIT:** I already have the code for reading the PS2 steering wheel, but now I need to "transform" that into PS4 protocol

Comment: I have just edited it. I want to know if there is a library that i can use to emulate a PS4 joystock using an Arduino UNO

Comment: Tie a string to the joystick and the sides of the steering wheel. So that when you turn the wheel, it pulls the thumbstick to left/right? Best case you can use an Arduino to replace the actual thumbsticks on a controller, by taking it apart.

Answer (score 2):

TLDR: Not sure but the PS4 protocol is known and written for other MCUs, and can be found on github.

Not sure if there is a library for it in Arduino, but there are libraries out there (such as Passing Link) that emulate the protocol on other platforms. You can look at that.

BUT...

PS2 and PS4 are completely different beasts. PS2 uses SPI for its protocol. PS4 uses USB with specific USB drivers. Even if you manage to get the PS4 protocol working, the next problem is authenticating you are a legit/licensed controller. For every legit controller, there lies a security chip inside. And that chip also has a proprietary way to be talked to as well. When a legit controller is talking to a PS4, the PS4 will sometimes ask for the contents in the security chip for authentication. If you can't deliver the contents it wants, your controller is locked out until next power up (maybe even next PS4 power up, not sure).

So while it may be possible, the two huge hurdles are:

1. Implementing the USB code properly with custom drivers defined by Sony.
2. Circumventing the security chip by either ripping contents off a legit controller or mining it and placing it in your own circuit. Both of which will require an understanding how how to communicate with said chip.